# "Параметры" или "Настройки"?

Tags: выбор-слов, синонимы, переводы

Я пишу приложение, у которого в интерфейсе есть окно, с помощью которого задаются настройки/параметры. В английском варианте оно называется "Settings".

Как лучше назвать это окно по-русски?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку мне очень часто приходится сталкиваться с принятием подобных решений по переводу, для себя выработал следующую терминологию, которая и была успешно принята в нашей компании:

- Settings, adjustments — это настройки.
- Options, preferences — это параметры.

Отклонение от этого правила может быть только в том (редком) случае, когда в одном приложении или даже в одном меню встречается и то, и это, например: Preferences — это общие настройки программы, а, скажем, Processing Options — параметры обработки.

Comment: Неплохо, тоже буду пользоваться этим. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

По-русски – настройки. А вот запускать программу можно с теми или иными параметрами (не с настройками).

Comment: Весьма спорное утверждение. "Настройка" сейчас не только и не столько действие по глаголу "настроить" (я и не сообразил сразу, о чем вы подумали), сколько именно "входные параметры".

Answer (score 0):

По-русски есть точный перевод settings = "установки". Но в контексте IT оно совершенно не используется. А было бы неплохо.

В остальном - см. Menelion Elensúlë